# Remote Access Cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

We are using cassandra enterprise editions. We have configured cluster from opscenter but we are unable to get access from Remote host. We are able to get access inside my DC from another host.

Please let me know how it can be resolved.

Note: There is no issue with firewalld.

Comment: Can you ping the C* nodes from the remote host?

Comment: Yes I can ping from remote host.

Comment: And you have verified that the C* process is running and it is really just cqlsh that cannot connect? Can you connect from the C* itself with cqlsh?

Comment: ping will check against ICMP port, use `telnet` command and make sure you can telnet to that node on port 9042 and 9160. If you are using AWS make sure your security rules are correct. Last from a remote box try using cqlsh to connect to remote host using `-h` option.